# Java Program to disassemble Java Byte Code

Tags: java, bytecode

I am recently reading about bytecode analysis and I need a help with the below query:

> Which JDK packages/APIs I have to look for if I wanted to write a Java program which disassembles a Java Byte Code (by reading a class file) and print Opcodes **without using any external libraries like ASM and without using `javap` command** ?

**In simple words, are there any JDK APIs available to disassemble Java Byte Code ?**

If possible, can anybody share a sample code snippet for doing the same ?

**This is purely for my understanding about the Core Java APIs support on bytecode and make myself aware if there any core Java libraries for byte code analysis.**

Thank you.

Comment: Someone has down voted this post without mentioning any reason..I really  would like to know the reason....please help.

Comment: I think it is a pretty reasonable question. +1

Comment: I think `javap` is just a wrapper which inturn calls a java library perform it's task. So what you are asking could very well be inside the JDK itself.

Comment: If you're looking for a code you could look inside the `rt.jar` of your jdk, you can look at these `package com.sun.tools.javap` , or look http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/javap/JavapTask.java/?v=source which has all the implementations there.

Comment: Sun's disassembler, now maintained by OpenJDK https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/Chapter+2#Chapter2-Jdis, has opened source and can be converted in a library.

Comment: I have edited my question as I am interested in only knowing the Core  Java APIs, if code snippet takes too long.

Comment: @vas31: then, it’s still an off-topic question as you are asking us to find you an off-site resource. Since the core Java API [is well documented and freely available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/), it’s easy for you to find out yourself whether such an API exists (it doesn’t). Still, it’s *of course* possible to implement such a thing atop the core API as that’s exactly what javap or ASM (or other tools) do, so that question is a tautology. It’s possible, not hard, but the code will exceed the scope of SO. [Start here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html)

Answer (score 3):

No there are no API's in the JRE for disassembling bytecode. Its easy to find out by looking at the javadoc package tree, the names already tell you about the scope of functionality found inside. Few are even remotely related and need checking out in detail.

Note that there is no javadoc for the com.sun packages and those are not considered part of the JDK.

But basically, everything *is* there. You can read files, and you can process them however you want. Documentation is also available about byte code and class files. So you *could* write everything yourself.

So...

> Can we write a simple Java program to disassemble Java Byte Code and print Opcodes without using any external libraries like ASM and without using javap command ?

Yes. (depends on what qualifies as *simple*, a pure disassembler falls on the boundary IMO).

> In other words, are there any JDK APIs available to disassemble Java Byte Code ?

No.

Comment: Durandal: Your answer is contradictory for the queries (1) & (2). Also please refer my query which I have updated recently. Thank you.

Comment: @vas31 There is no contradiction as per the original question and there is also no contradiction for your updated question.