# Warning: main methods should not be directly called

Tags: java, program-entry-point, compiler-warnings, checkstyle, static-code-analysis

I currently work on a Java project which has many `main` methods. Now, I do some refactoring, which affects all `main` methods. However, some of the `main` methods are actually called directly from other methods. I think this is bad style and it actually makes the refactoring harder. Thus, I want to be able to identify all places where a `main` method is called. Currently, I use my IDE tools to find all references to a given `main` method, however this is tedious and it is easy to forget to check this for one of the `main` methods.

My question is, whether there is some checkstyle rule or Eclipse compiler warnings setting that produces a warning whenever a `main` method is called directly. I was unable to find one.

Comment: This is off topic (question asking for tool, etc), but how about searching "main(" to find calls? And why do this make refactoring harder ?

Comment: @RC. You are right. I edited the question, so it no longer asks for a tool. String searches are not the right tool to find method calls. This is what static code analysis exists for. Searching for text is likely to miss calls that contain confusing formatting.

Comment: @RC. It actually does make the refactoring harder. I don't want to go into the details, because they are off-topic for this question.

Comment: if searching is not an option, then add a new main(), and with some reflection, find all methods named `main` (but the new used to search) in all the code base (see [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) for example), this will not miss any method because of formatting

Comment: @RC. Thanks for the suggestion. However, I think this will only find the method declarations, right? I want to find the places where a main method is called (the usages). I don't think this can be done via reflection, can it?

Comment: From the link I gave you: `Set<Member> usages =     reflections.getMethodUsages(Method.class)` (never tried that however)

Comment: public\s+static\s+void\s+main\s*\(\s*String\[\] is a regex that should find almost any main method you might have in your program - you can use the checkstyle plugin to find any method that has a different order of public, static, and void. It'll grab stuff that's commented out, but you can prune those from your search results in Eclipse pretty easily. Then, when you find a main method, set it to private or comment it out. Chase down the resulting compile errors... should work.

Comment: or you could use Eclipse's Java search. Search for 'main', only searching for 'Method' with Limit to 'References' with Search in 'Sources' with a scope of your project.

Comment: @RC. I must have missed this part of the README when I shortly looked into it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeutnarg Thanks for the suggestion. This will work, but I was looking for a more automated way. Manually finding the main methods and finding the usages for a given main method is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jeutnarg suggested in the comments:

> [...] you could use Eclipse's Java search. Search for 'main', only searching for 'Method' with Limit to 'References' with Search in 'Sources' with a scope of your project.

This is what I ended up doing and it actually worked much better than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned that people may have formatted the "main" methods in variety of ways, and that you may miss some of them when you use "pattern matching" ...

Could "javap -public MyClass.class" work for you? When I tried it on ...

```
    public class Main1 {
         public
    static
                    void
    main
    (
                    String
    []
    args
                    )
    {
            System.out.println("Main1: Hello World");
         }
    }
```

It produced the following output:

```
    Compiled from "Main1.java"
    public class Main1 {
      public Main1();
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    }
```

Admittedly, it doesn't 'detect' if this 'main' is calling another 'main', it will be helpful just in finding all the 'main's.

Source derived from Post: [Java Program to disassemble Java Byte Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073897/java-program-to-disassemble-java-byte-code)

Comment: I like the idea. The `javap` output is pretty standardized, so a text search should not miss some occurrences. However, it will only be really helpful if it is possible to search it for method calls. I will look into this.